# case-insensitive validation using phalcon validation class

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

In validation class my `intiialize` function is like this

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->add('gender',new InclusionIn(array(
           'message' => 'Please enter a valid Gender',
           'domain' => array('Male','Female'),
           'case_insensitive' => false
    )));
}
```

Problem is, `InclusionIn` makes a case-sensitive validation so if user enter "male" application throws an error **Please enter a valid Gender**. I want this validation should be `case-insensitive` but I did not find any way to do it.

Comment: I think you can write your own validator to prefer this option. see this [Doc](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/validation.html#validators).

Comment: So you mean there is no option provided by Phalcon in `InclusionIn` class to make case-insensitive check ??

Comment: Yes, because of the [Main API Doc](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Validation_Validator_InclusionIn.html) i think there is no option. but also you can ask in [Phalcon Forum](https://forum.phalconphp.com/) .

Comment: Thank you @M2sh for link and guidance, writing your own `validator` was solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @M2sh & @honerlawd guided, finally I ended with writing a new validator for 'inclusion` sharing the code here

```
<?php

namespace library\app\validators;

use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator;
use Phalcon\Validation\Exception;
use Phalcon\Validation\Message;

class InclusionIn extends Validator
{

    /**
     * Executes the validation
     */
    public function validate(Validation $validation, $attribute)
    {

        $value = $validation->getValue($attribute);

        if ($this->isSetOption("allowEmpty") && empty($value)) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * A domain is an array with a list of valid values
         */
        $domain = $this->getOption("domain");
        if (!is_array($domain)) {
            throw new Exception("Option 'domain' must be an array");
        }
        $refinedDomain = array_map('strtolower', $domain);

        $strict = false;
        if ($this->isSetOption("strict")) {
            if (!is_bool($strict)) {
                throw new Exception("Option 'strict' must be a boolean");
            }

            $strict = $this->getOption("strict");
        }

        /**
         * Check if the value is contained by the array
         */
        if (!in_array(strtolower($value), $refinedDomain, $strict)) {

            $label = $this->getOption("label");
            if (empty($label)) {
                $label = $validation->getLabel($attribute);
            }

            $message = $this->getOption("message");
            $replacePairs = ['field' => $label, 'domain' => join(", ", $domain)];
            if (empty($message)) {
                $message = $validation->getDefaultMessage("InclusionIn");
            }

            $validation->appendMessage(new Message(strtr($message, $replacePairs), $attribute, "InclusionIn"));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`InclusionIn` uses `in_array` which is case sensitive. You would have to write your own `Validator` in order to get the functionality you would need. [Here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/validation/validator/inclusionin.zep) is the implementation of the class so you can see what options are available.

Another option is just to format the input before the validator is fired. e.g. if they type in `male` or `MALE` convert it to `Male` so the validation will pass.

Comment: Thank you @honerlawd for sharing the important link it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

In case of validating model, you can use `beforeValidation()`, `beforeValidationOnCreate()` or `beforeValidationOnUpdate()` to lowercase/uppercase value:

```
function beforeValidation() {
    $this->gender = ucfirst($this->gender);
}
```

If validating via [Forms](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/filter.html), you can apply `addFilter(lower)` and validate for lowercase eg.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use filter see phalcon Filtering and Sanitizing https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/filter.html

In controller like this: note filter need to be added to services initialisation

```
$gender = $this->filter->sanitize($gender, "lower");
```

OR

In your customValidation class:

```
class MyValidation extends Validation 
{
    public function initialize()
    {
       $this->add('gender',new InclusionIn(array(
         'message' => 'Please enter a valid Gender',
         'domain' => array('male','female'),
       )));

       $this->setFilters('gender', 'lower');
    }
}
```